Out of memory error in Excel 365 running VBA script
I had an excel file with about 10K records that I split into multiple files. All with the same structure but each around 1500 records. 1 file has the remaining 900 records plus the 1500 (so, about 2500 ish). I have the below VBA script I'm running against the files. The script has run against 2 of the files successfully. However, I'm getting out of memory errors when I try to run the script against the next file. But the file is basically the same size as the other files (1500 records). I've even restarted the machine, but still getting the error. Tried asking the AI's, but got nothing helpful.
The machine I'm working on has 64 gigs of RAM, core i9 and I'm using excel 365 (updated to my release ring).
Why is the script running successfully in 2 of the other copies of the file, but not in the 3rd???
Sub CleanAccentsInData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, batchSize As Long, batchStart As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Set the worksheet name where your data is located
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EvaCombined4")  ' Replace " EvaCombined4" with your actual sheet name
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet not found, check the name and try again.", vbCritical
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    batchSize = 20  ' Try an even smaller batch size

    ' Process data in batches
    For batchStart = 2 To lastRow Step batchSize
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(batchStart, 1), ws.Cells(Min(batchStart + batchSize - 1, lastRow), 43))
        dataArray = rng.Value

        ' Process each cell in the array
        For i = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 2)
                If VarType(dataArray(i, j)) = vbString And Not IsEmpty(dataArray(i, j)) Then
                    dataArray(i, j) = CleanText(CStr(dataArray(i, j)))
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        rng.Value = dataArray  ' Write back the processed data
        Set rng = Nothing ' Explicitly clear the range object
        Erase dataArray ' Clear the array
    Next batchStart

CleanUp:
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    MsgBox "Data cleaning complete!", vbInformation
End Sub

Function Min(a As Long, b As Long) As Long
    If a < b Then
        Min = a
    Else
        Min = b
    End If
End Function

Function CleanText(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim ch As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Const AccChars = "àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ"
    Const RegChars = "aaaaaaceeeeiiiionooooouuuuyyAAAAAACEEEEIIIIONOOOOOUUUUY"

    result = text
    For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        result = Replace(result, Mid(AccChars, i, 1), Mid(RegChars, i, 1))
    Next i

    CleanText = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(result)
        ch = Mid(result, i, 1)
        If ch Like "[a-zA-Z] " Then
            CleanText = CleanText & ch
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(CleanText) = 0 Then CleanText = result ' Return original if cleaning results in an empty string
End Function



I don't see anything that could cause an out of mem error. Which statement throws the error? Anything special in that worksheet?

It fails when running.

Yes, but does it show a line in the VBA editor?

Oddly, no it doesn't.

Most of the characters contained in the AccChars constant are Unicode characters that are not supported by the VBA editor. Instead of graphic forms, their codes should be used.
In addition, there was an error in the spelling of the Like condition.
Suggested modified code:
Option Explicit
Const RegChars = "aaaaaaceeeeiiiionooooouuuuyyAAAAAACEEEEIIIIONOOOOOUUUUY"
Dim AccChars As String
Sub DefineChars()
  '  Const AccChars = "àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ"
    Dim ach As Variant, a As Variant
    ach = Array(224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, _
                241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 255, 192, 193, 194, 195, _
                196, 197, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, _
                213, 214, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221)
    
                ' 224:229, 231:246, 249:253, 255, 192:197, 199:214, 217:221
    
    For Each a In ach
        AccChars = AccChars & ChrW(a)
    Next a
End Sub

Sub CleanAccentsInData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, batchSize As Long, batchStart As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Set the worksheet name where your data is located
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EvaCombined4")  ' Replace " EvaCombined4" with your actual sheet name
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet not found, check the name and try again.", vbCritical
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    DefineChars

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    batchSize = 20  ' Try an even smaller batch size

    ' Process data in batches
    For batchStart = 2 To lastRow Step batchSize
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(batchStart, 1), ws.Cells(Min(batchStart + batchSize - 1, lastRow), 43))
        dataArray = rng.Value

        ' Process each cell in the array
        For i = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 2)
                If VarType(dataArray(i, j)) = vbString And Not IsEmpty(dataArray(i, j)) Then
                    dataArray(i, j) = CleanText(CStr(dataArray(i, j)))
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        rng.Value = dataArray  ' Write back the processed data
        Set rng = Nothing ' Explicitly clear the range object
        Erase dataArray ' Clear the array
    Next batchStart

CleanUp:
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    MsgBox "Data cleaning complete!", vbInformation
End Sub

Function Min(a As Long, b As Long) As Long
    If a < b Then
        Min = a
    Else
        Min = b
    End If
End Function

Function CleanText(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim ch As String
    Dim i As Integer

    result = text
    For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        result = Replace(result, Mid(AccChars, i, 1), Mid(RegChars, i, 1))
    Next i

    CleanText = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(result)
        ch = Mid(result, i, 1)
        If ch Like "[a-zA-Z ]" Then    ' <- change here
            CleanText = CleanText & ch
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(CleanText) = 0 Then CleanText = result ' Return original if cleaning results in an empty string
End Function


Thanks @Mgonet.
Just to make sure, you're suggesting I replace the code from my script starting at:
Function CleanText(ByVal text As String) As String
Dim result As String
Dim ch As String
Dim i As Integer
with the script you provided and keep the rest of the script preceding that?
Thanks!

This code that I published is intended to replace your code entirely. There is also a change in the line with Like. The behavior of this code may depend on the code page/language version you are using. My code page is suitable for Central Europe.

Muuuuuuuch better script! Thanks very much @MGonet!
